# Why i can't return my method?

Tags: c#, forms, methods, combobox, enums

I have an enum that contains some languages like English, French, Spanish, German ...

I have the below method to return a comboBox instance that has the enum as DataSource:

```
  public ComboBox UpdateComboBoxIdioma()
        {
            comboIdioma.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Idioms)); 
            return comboIdioma;//it return 6 languages
        }
```

I am assigning the resulted comboBox of the method to the comboBox in a form, to show my languages like this:

```
comboBox2 = classeDefinicoes.UpdateComboBoxIdioma();
```

But it does not show the languages on the form.

What could be the problem?

Comment: "classeDefinicoes" is also a variable of "SettingsClass classeDefinicoes = new SettingsClass();"

Comment: where have you define comboIdioma?

Comment: Are you getting blank rows or no rows in the comboBox.

Comment: @Nikita I don't have any null row when return instruction occurs

Comment: comboIdioma is a variable for constructor defined in my form "form.cs"

Comment: please post the complete code of class `SettingsClass`

Comment: check my second comment about data in combobox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it is not a good idea to return a combo control from a method. Instead you should simply get the values from the `Idioms` enum and set it as `DataSource` of the combo like this -

```
var comboSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Idioms));
this.comboBox2.DataSource = comboSource;
```

or like this if you prefer one liners :)

```
this.comboBox2.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Idioms));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a `Form` and `SettingsClass`:

I tried to reproduce what you are trying to say. I have added a `ComboBox` and a `Button` to my `Form`. In the Button Click event, I set the `ComboBox` value like you gave. Code is as follows:

**Form1.cs:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{       
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    SettingsClass classeDefinicoes;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         classeDefinicoes = new SettingsClass();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox2 = classeDefinicoes.UpdateComboBoxIdioma();
    }        
}
```

**SettingsClass.cs:**

```
class SettingsClass
{
    enum Idioms
    {
        English, French, Spanish, German
    }

    ComboBox comboIdioma;

    public SettingsClass()
    {
        comboIdioma = new ComboBox();
    }

    public ComboBox UpdateComboBoxIdioma()
    {
        comboIdioma.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Idioms));
        return comboIdioma;//it return 6 languages
    }
}
```

Using this code, even I dont get any languages in the `ComboBox` in the form. When I change my `Button` Click event as follows, I get the items in the `ComboBox`.

**Changed `Button` Click event:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox2.DataSource = classeDefinicoes.UpdateComboBoxIdioma().DataSource;
}
```

**Update:**

You have to set the `DataSource` property to get the changes. Merely assigning the returning `ComboBox` to the `ComboBox` in the form is not sufficient to display the items.

What Yogi says is also right. If you want to follow what he says then the code becomes something like this:

**SettingsClass.cs:**:

```
class SettingsClass
{
    enum Idioms
    {
        English, French, Spanish, German
    }

    public Array UpdateComboBoxIdioma()
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(Idioms));
    }
}
```

**Changed `Button` Click event:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox2.DataSource = classeDefinicoes.UpdateComboBoxIdioma();
}
```